# Mac OS X: Managing Windows

Tags: macos, user-experience, window-manager

So here is my problem, originally I'm a Windows user and developerr, and now I have a Mac OS based machine, I'm developing on Mac OS X as well, but the problem is that on Windows I feel comfortable with a lot of open windows (notepad, editors, browser etc) and switching between them is easy. While on Mac OS X I feel not that comfortable, because I don't know how to quickly switch between windows, maybe there is some kind of softawre where I can see all open windows. So I could quickly swith windows.

*Maybe you could give some advices how you organize your screen, what software you're using, shortcuts, etc.*

Answer (score 7):

I make extensive use of Expose in that case.

Comment: If you're not familiar with Exposé, you can tune its settings via the `Exposé and Spaces` System Preferences pane.  In general, its features are accessible via `F9`, `F10`, and `F11` keys.

Answer (score 5):

Expose and the shortcut keys for switching windows are very good built-in methods of seeing all your windows. You might also want to take a look at [Witch](http://manytricks.com/witch/) and [Optimal Layout](http://most-advantageous.com/optimal-layout/) for add-on capabilities.

[image: Witch]

[image: Optimal Layout]

Answer (score 3):

I use a few things for this, with Exposé being the most important. I usually use it when I have a ton of stuff open and want to switch apps quickly.

Spaces can also be nice. When I'm using a one-monitor setup, I'll often have a space set aside for e-mail and twitter, with another one for my browser and editors. Most of the time, though, I have two screens, so I don't bother with Spaces. (If you want to use it, it's in the same area in System Preferences as Exposé.

Next is **Command-Tab** for switching between apps. It works just like alt-tab does on Windows, and holding shift lets you switch backwards, just like it does on Windows.

The one that usually gets overlooked (but I use all the time) is **Command-`**. (That's the tickmark to the left of the #1 key.) It lets you switch between windows within one app. Again, hold shift to start switching backwards. I use this a ton with MS Word and Safari.

Comment: On international English keyboard, the tickmark is to the left of z.

Comment: Didn't know about the command-tickmark. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Previously (pre 10.5) i made extensive use of:

Exposé -> to navigate the windows of the current program, i had it set to mouse gestures to easily show all windows

Command + Tab -> navigate between programs

[Quicksilver](http://github.com/tiennou/blacktree-alchemy) -> quickly open finder windows to a specific directory

Command + h -> quickly hide a progam.

this was my workflow going between Adobe CS applications, web browsers, terminal windows, and itunes.

Comment: +1 for Cmd-H, although the Exposé behaviour is a bit weird starting with 10.6 (minimized windows of hidden apps are shown, the others not).

Comment: agreed, i left that job before 10.6 and haven't use OSX that much since.

Answer (score 1):

Other window managers out there:

Divvy by Mizage.  Uses a unique grid for laying out windows

Cinch by Irradiated Software.  Aero Snap like window management.

SizeUp by Irradiated Software.  Keyboard shortcut based, many options including moving windows between monitors and Spaces.

Breeze by AutumnApps.  Save the size/position of a window and restore it later.

Comment: I've been using Divvy for a while now and very much recommend it

Answer (score 0):

You can use cmd-tab to switch between applications and cmd-~ to switch between windows in the same application. (This corresponds to alt-tab and ctrl-tab on Windows.)

You can see all open windows and navigate between them using Expose (usually on F9 to F11 keys, I think; check in System Preferences).

Using a combination of the function keys for Expose and multiple desktops and cmd-tab and cmd-~ I can navigate on Mac OS much faster than on Windows.

Comment: The modifier on Mac OS X to switch between windows is ⌘ (command), not ⌥ (alt).

Answer (score 0):

I am in the same boat with you.  I enjoy mac osx except for the crazy window management.

To fix this I have enabled the setting in Dock < system preferences to minimize windows into their icon.

I also edited DockMenus.plist in System/Library/CoreServices/Dock/Contents/Resources to remove the quit, hide, ... etc options from the right click menu.  Now I can right click on the icon to switch between my currently opened windows.  The image below demonstrates what I am talking about.

[image]